# Can one obtain a distance transform of an image along with angle information?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

Is it possible to obtain a distance transform with the distance (float) and angle (in radians) from the nearest pixel?

I would be using `python` and the library I am currently relying on is `opencv-python`, although I am open to whatever works.

Comment: afaik there is one method that delivers both, the distance and the actual pixel position of the nearest point. From that you can compute the angle yourself.

Comment: `dst, labels = cv.distanceTransformWithLabels` you can find information about the needed parameters and interpretation here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042